# how to install 2 simple ssl certificates on 2 web site having the same ip, in iis8?

Tags: iis, ssl, ip, nlb

how  to add a second ssl certificate to the same server for two different web sites?. How to setup a second ip for the second web site considering that the server is balanced?

more information:

i've bought an ssl certificate for subdomain1.domain1.com from a CA

and a second ssl certificate fom sobdomain2.domain1.com from another CA

i've installed all the 2 certificates.

And i've configured certificate 1 for subdomain1.domain1.com from a CA

When i try to add the certificate2 for the binding of sobdomain2.domain1.com

i get this error message:

"At least one other site is using the same HTTPS binding and the binding is configured with a different certificate. Are you sure that you want to reuse this HTTPS binding and reassign the other site or sites to use the new certificate?"

I know it is because ssl on iis is ip based,so 
how can i add a second ip to the server in order to make the second ssl working?
The server is load balanced

Comment: You're going to have to offer a bit more information..

Comment: i've added more info

Answer (score 0):

SNI (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) could be used to allow several distinct certificates on a single IP address, provided that you trust your user base to have SNI-capable clients, and provided that your server supports SNI.

The other way would be to use several IP addresses on each server handling the subdomains, and also to correspondingly have several distinct IP addresses on the load balancer which is forwarding the traffic to the real servers (assuming here that the LB works at TCP/IP level, and does not itself terminate the SSL traffic).

You would get more to-the-point responses if you described the models and versions of the web servers and load balancers you're using; with this information, only this kind of paraphrasing responses are possible.

Comment: i'm trying to create a sni followinf microsoft guide http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability but i get this error: unable to remove the certificate.